# How to set value of date picker in macOS?

Tags: macos, xcode-ui-testing

The recorder generated the following code, but `click()` always clicks on the year field. I did click on the individual fields when recording.

```
    let startDateDatePicker = sheetsQuery.datePickers["Start Date"]
    startDateDatePicker.click()
    startDateDatePicker.typeText("1")
    startDateDatePicker.click()
    startDateDatePicker.typeText("1")
    startDateDatePicker.click()
    startDateDatePicker.typeText("2016")
```

What is the recommended way to set a date picker UI element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`startDateDatePicker.dateValue = foo`?

EDIT: Now that I know what you're actually trying to do, try this:

```
datePicker.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.1, dy: 0.5)).click()
datePicker.typeText("1")
datePicker.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.3, dy: 0.5)).click()
datePicker.typeText("2")
datePicker.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.6, dy: 0.5)).click()
datePicker.typeText("1934")
```

Comment: This was the first thing I tried. `error: <EXPR>:3:1: error: value of type 'XCUIElement' has no member 'dateValue'`

Comment: In the future, please be more specific about your question. Your question only asks "What is the recommended way to set a date picker UI element?" without mentioning that you are accessing the date picker through Xcode's UI testing mechanism rather than directly. The provided answer is the correct answer for the former question, which has a different answer from the latter.

Comment: I've updated with the solution to your problem. Please remove the downvote.

Comment: Dude, no need to be pushy. I think my original question was completely clear.